# ffmpeg webm vs mp4 quality issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, mp4, webm

I have a series of `.jpg` files in a directory that I want to turn into the movie with `ffmpeg`.  When I make a `.mp4` file of all the jpegs, the video quality is pretty much the same as the original images.  When I make a `.webm` file though, it looks very blocky.  These are the two commands I'm using:

```
$ ffmpeg -i %10d.jpg -s 640x480 -r 16 test.mp4

$ ffmpeg -i %10d.jpg -s 640x480 -r 16 test.webm
```

I know next to nothing about video encoding so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-qscale n` when ’n’ is between 1 (excellent quality) and 31 (worst quality).

This actually sets a constant quality but variable bitrate.

So now your code will look something like this when you set qscale 1:

```
ffmpeg -i %10d.jpg -s 640x480 -r 16 -qscale 1 test.webm
```

Sometimes it outputs an error as `qscale` is ambiguous. In such cases, use `-q:v 1` instead of `-qscale 1`.

Now if you still want better quality, set the bit rate too for your output file to 320 kbs.

Now code will be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 320k -q:v 0 output.webm
```

If you are still not satisfied with the quality, try this code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.webm
```

Explanation of the above so that you change it according to your needs:

- `-profile:v high`: Sets H.264 profile to high. You can also use baseline,main.
- `-preset slow`: Sets encoding preset for x264 (slower presets give more quality at same bitrate, but takes more time to encode); can also use ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow.
- `-b:v`: Sets video bitrate in bits/s.
- `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`: Maximum rate to be streamed 500kbit/s also looking into device buffer of 1000kbits.
- `-vf scale`: Used for scaling video, based upon your requirements you can use this.
- `-threads 0`: Choose optimal number of threads to encode.
- `-codec:a libfdk_aac`: Sets encoder to aac through libfdk-aac library
- `-b:a`: Sets audio bitrate